# Velocity response writer is not working in Solr

Tags: java, solr, velocity

I am trying to get the Velocity interface up and running using the documentation from Solr (8.0.0), but I'm always getting the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org/apache/solr/response/QueryResponseWriter

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.response.QueryResponseWriter
```

I've tryied many configurations, putting the lib folder in the core, in the solr home, in the server root... passing it through the solrconfig.xml.

Even in the standard example "techproduct" velocity is not working.

In the solrconfig i've added the following code:

```
...
  <!--<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-ltr-\d.*\.jar" />-->
<lib dir="../lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
...
  <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter">
    <str name="template.base.dir">${velocity.template.base.dir:}</str>
    <!--
  <str name="init.properties.file">velocity-init.properties</str>
  <bool name="params.resource.loader.enabled">true</bool>
  <bool name="solr.resource.loader.enabled">false</bool>
  <lst name="tools">
    <str name="mytool">com.example.MyCustomTool</str>
  </lst>
-->
  </queryResponseWriter>
...
  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler" useParams="query,facets,velocity,browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Any suggesions?

Comment: Which version of Velocity are you using?

Comment: The default provided in solr 8.0.0

Comment: try by copying the jar "solr-velocity-7.5.0" from "D:\solr-7.5.0\solr-7.5.0\dist" to "D:\solr-7.5.0\solr-7.5.0\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib"

Comment: Thank you, that fix the problem. They should advertise this in the Apache Solr configuration guide because it is totally unclear.

Comment: Your set of `lib` directives is commented out - `<!--` .. remove that instead of moving the jar files. jar files are loaded from the `lib` directories as given in your configuration, but not if you've commented out the directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the jar `"solr-velocity-7.5.0"` from `"D:\solr-7.5.0\solr-7.5.0\dist"` to `"D:\solr-7.5.0\solr-7.5.0\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib"`.

The generic would be copy the `"solr-velocity-7.5.0"` jar from `"...\solr-7.5.0\dist"` to `"...\solr-7.5.0\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib"`

Note: The folder location can different on the linux or other operating system.

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration given above the lib directive that loads the velocity libraries is commented out. In XML anything between `<!--` and `-->` is considered a comment:

```
 <!--<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  ...
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-ltr-\d.*\.jar" />-->
```

Remove the comments and restart - `lib` directives are the suggested way of loading libraries, since it allows you to easily switch which libraries are loaded and available for which core, instead of having to remember to copy libraries into a specific location after installing a core or upgrading Solr.

Comment: The log when starting Solr should show you which directories and jar files the server is loading. This is [the suggested way for how you should load external dependencies](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html).